# Reactjs delete an item from Dexie.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dexie

This example uses Reactjs and [Dexie.js.](https://github.com/dfahlander/Dexie.js/wiki/API%20Reference) I have a CRUD app without the D, which I presently require. While you can enter and store new items into the database, I am not sure how to select each item that has been added and delete them. I understand that you have to select them through their ID.

With the i tag I have attached a `.onClick={this.removal}`. However, I am unsure what to add to the `removal` function.

```
 var datastored = new Dexie('MyPlace');
datastored.version(1).stores({entries:'++id, title, entry' });
datastored.open().catch(function(err){alert("Could not open database:"+err)});

var Dashboard = React.createClass({
 getInitialState:function(){
  return {results: [] }
  },

runcheck:function(){
  let arr = [];
  datastored.entries
  .each((uploaded)=>arr.push(uploaded))
  .then(()=>this.setState({results:arr}));    
},   

componentDidMount:function(){
  this.runcheck();
},

removal:function(){
  datastored.entries.delete();    
},    

sendthru:function(){
  var newInput = {
  title: this.inputTitle.value,
  entry: this.inputEntry.value    
  };
  datastored.entries.add(newInput).then(()=>this.runcheck());   
  this.inputTitle.value = '';    
  this.inputEntry.value = '';     
},

renderdem:function(){
   var list = this.state.results.map(result =>{
    return <tr key={result.id}>
        <td>{result.id}</td> 
        <td>{result.title}</td> 
        <td>{result.entry}
        <i className="fa fa-times-circle exout" aria-hidden="true" onClick={this.removal}></i>
        </td>
    </tr>
});       
return (<div>
    <p>Title</p>        
    <input type="text" id="inputname" className="form-control" ref={el => this.inputTitle = el} />
    <p>Entry</p>        
    <textarea id="inputentry" ref={el => this.inputEntry = el} className="form-control"></textarea>
<button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.sendthru}>Add</button>        
        <table className="table table-bordered"><tbody>{list}</tbody></table>
</div>);   
},    

render:function(){
  return this.renderdem();}        
});

ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

I have included my code in JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/5uevnock/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed you need to pass id in order to know what to remove. However, you cannot delete the entry immediately when binding the `removal` function to `onClick`. The trick here is to make `removal` return a function that will get called when on click happens.

```
removal:function(id){
  var component = this;
  return function(evt) {
    datastored.entries.delete(id);   
    component.runcheck();
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<i className="fa fa-times-circle exout" aria-hidden="true" onClick={this.removal(result.id)}></i>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/u1vfoqgp/